# Using custom attributes and namespace in android

Tags: android, namespaces

The package structure is basically: `app>src>main>com.example.customviews` inside which a `view` folder exists that contains the `CustomView.java` file.

Inside the `attrs.xml` file in the `res` folder I define a `stylable` as so:

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="PieChart">
        <attr name="showText" format="boolean"/>
        <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
            <enum name="left" value="0"/>
            <enum name="right" value="1"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>  
</resources>
```

In the `activity_main.xml`(`Mainactivity.java` also being in the `com.example.customviews` directory) I tried to define a namespace for my custom attributes like so:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

...
...
...  

</LinearLayout>
```

But for the namespace defined, android gives me the following error message in the editor:

> In Gradle projects, always use http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto for custom attributes less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>      Inspection info:In Gradle projects, the actual package used in the final APK can vary; for example,you can add a .debug package suffix in one version and not the other. Therefore, you should not hardcode the application package in the resource; instead, use the special namespace http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto which will cause the tools to figure out the right namespace for the resource regardless of the actual package used during the build.

This brings the following two questions in mind:

1. What does the  URI `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` do, is
   it dynamically resolved by android? Like for `app` namespace it is
   resolved to one URI and for `custom` namespace it is used for
   another?
2. [The android documentation uses a custom URI like I defined
   above](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view#java), why is the error raised by android studio when I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need a custom namespace.  If your customviews package is included in your project, its attrs will be merged into your projects, and you can just use app: for them.

Comment: Hm.... but why does the android doc use it and.... what does the sentence " ... cause the tools to figure out the right namespace" mean when we use the `"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` namespace?